# maya api vs python commands: vertex normals

Tags: python, maya, maya-api

I'm trying to extract the vertex normal of a mesh object at a particular vertex. I've noticed that I get different results when using the python API instead of the maya python commands.

**Python commands (gives me the result i want)**:

```
cmds.polyNormalPerVertex("<myshapename>.vtx[523]", q=True,normalXYZ=True)
```

**The maya python API call (gives me a different result)**:

```
# empty selection list
selectionList = om.MSelectionList()
selectionList.add(<myshapename>)

# create empty dag path object
dagPath = selectionList.getDagPath(0)

# get mesh 
mesh = om.MFnTransform(dagPath)

# get vertex normal
mesh.getVertexNormal(523, False, space=om.MSpace.kWorld)
```

I noticed this discrepancy when trying to extract normals on an object whose vertices are on the seam border with another object. The normals have been averaged in maya using `Normals > Average Normals` from the `Polygons` menu set.

I know it's difficult without an example object, but I'm hoping somebody has seen this problem before.

Can anyone provide a possible explanation for this discrepancy?

Answer (score 2):

I think you just got lucky with your cmds call. The usual behavior for `polyNormalPerVertex` is to return *all* of the normals associated with the vert -- which, if it is part of more than one face, will be multiple answers to the same question.  For example on a vanilla `polyCube`

import maya.cmds as cmds
   cmds.polyNormalPerVertex('pCube1.vtx[0]', q=True, normalXYZ=True)
   # Result: [-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0] #

since the vert is part of three different faces.

The API call to `getVertexNormal` will return the averaged normal, [according to the docs](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2009help/api/class_m_fn_mesh.html#7f471cea08bc45a9ec96d1cca8c0f2d5).

You should have better luck if you use vertexFaces in both ends -- those are less ambiguous.

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer. However, even averaging the results from `polyNormalPerVertex` does not equal the vector returned by `getVertexNormal` (and I've tried all combinations of parameters). Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: They should be the same if you pick the correct weighting function -- but that is going to be recalculated each time you ask and could change if, for example, you move a vert on the other side of the same face.